# jQuery .css(), and css hover

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having problems with the `.css()` in jQuery.

I have a mouseover css menu, but when I put this:

```
$(this).siblings().css({backgroundColor:"#eee"});
```

into the last part of my code my mouseover function doesn't works

```
$(".principal").click(function()
{
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#861b1b"}).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).siblings().css({backgroundColor:"#eee"});
});
```

So, the main issue is that my meny works with css :hover but I'm obligated to change back the P color to gray, so is there any method to fix this problem?

```
<div>
    <span>Ventanas</span>
    <p class="principal">Fijas</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
    <a href="products.php?ref=fijo&tipo=7001ad">Normal (7001)</a>
    <a href="products.php?ref=fijo&tipo=7001ad">Normal (7001)</a>
    <a href="products.php?ref=fijo&tipo=7001ad">Normal (7001)</a>
    <a href="products.php?ref=fijo&tipo=7001ad">Normal (7001)</a>
    </div>
</div>



    div.sdmenu div p {
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
}

div.sdmenu div p:hover {
    background:#841c1c;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It would help to see your mouseover code/css and html.

Comment: In your example $(".principal").click(function(){...}) but you mentioned mouseover ?

Comment: Put your code there and provide us the link: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fAQFS/ (note: Code is within a `$(document).ready` handler).

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the console?

Comment: when i click in it once it works fine the BG cahnges when i mouseover but wen i clik later.. i can't cahge the BG on moseover..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the syntax you use here:

```
$(this).siblings().css({backgroundColor:"#eee"});
```

use it without the {} for the CSS element, like this:

```
$(this).siblings().css(backgroundColor,#eee);
```

the syntax is: .css( propertyName, value )